How to kill the Benevito Axe Wielding giant economically?
There is a huge monster wielding an axe guarding the Benevito treasure. It seems to have a lot of hit points. It was still standing after getting 10 headshots with the FR F2 rifle which would cost 10k. So is whatever crystal thingy it drops would have to be over 10k Lei in value to make this worth it. Is there a better damage for the buck option?

Yes, the item you get is worth more than 10K Lei, according to IGN.

Collect Beneviento's Treasure


 Should you defeat the giant, you’ll gain a Giant Crystal Axe that sells for a 30,000 Lei, and if that wasn’t enough, you can now put the Broken Slab at the foot of the tombstone, and it will reveal Berengario’s Chalice which also sells for 18,000 Lei!

...
https://www.reddit.com/r/residentevil/comments/nl7aix/re8_enemy_damage_factor_table/
The "Urias Drac" has 22000 HP
Village of Shadows difficulty has you do 1/5 of Casual difficulty damage.
The best place to hit is the back of the torso. The head gives 80% of torso-back damage, with the worst being everywhere else for 2/3 of torso-back damage.
The Knife deals 2/3 of gun damage, assuming they're the same "weapon base damage".

Thanks a lot, I certainly did not expect such detailed answer. I am playing on normal difficulty - I wasn't able to get through the first part on hardcore and tbh... most of the enemies are more tedious than hard and I am guessing that would only be worse on hardcore and up.

@TomášZato - You're welcome! I haven't played the game so I'm giving the most info so you can use your knowledge! Have fun!
